# How to find the domain of a composition of rational functions

Tags: functions

> ($8$ points) Suppose that
>   $$f(x) = \frac1{x - 3} \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = \frac{x - 7}{x + 5}$$
>   For each function $h$ given below, find a formula for $h(x)$ and the domain of $h$. Use interval notation.
>
> (A)$\hspace{0.2cm}$ $h(x) = (f \circ g)(x)$

I suppose that the domain would be $(−\infty,−11) \cup (−11, \infty)$. However it shows me wrong. Could anyone help to obtain the correct answer?

Comment: You should first give the $f: A\to B$ and $g: A'\to B'$, what is A, B, A' and B'?

Comment: Don't post images, instead learn to typeset math with MathJax. Since you're new this time I did it for you, but next time I won't.

Comment: ok i will be aware next time

Answer (score 5):

The domain of $f\circ g$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-11,-5\}=(-\infty,-11)\cup(-11,-5)\cup(-5,+\infty)$. That's because:

- the function $g$ is undefined at $-5$ and only at $-5$;
- the function $f$ is undefined at $3$ and only at $3$ and $-11$ is the solution of the equation $g(x)=3$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $h(x)=f(g(x))$.

Thus, by definition 
$$D(h)=D(g)\cap\{x|g(x)\in D(f)\}.$$

$$h(x)=f(g(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{x-7}{x+5}-3}=-\frac{x+5}{2x+22}$$
and the domain of $h$  is $\mathbb R\setminus\{-11,-5\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$(f\cdot g)(x)$ can be rewritten as $f(g(x))$, which implies that you are computing the function $f$ of $g(x)$, and since $g(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x-7}{x+5}$, it can be inferred that you are in essence computing $f\left(\displaystyle \frac{x-7}{x+5}\right)$. After you've computed this, you should find the values where $g(f(x))$ is not defined, and then exclude them from your domain. Hopefully this gives you some insight?

Comment: You mixed it up. $(f \circ g)(x)$ is $f(g(x))$, yes, but then you go on to compute $g(f(x))$.

Comment: @rubik I just noticed and fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I can see why you came to the answer $(-\infty,-11) \cup (-11, \infty)$. That's because if you compute your $f\circ g$ as a symbolic expression, you get: \[\frac{1}{\frac{x-7}{x+5}-3} = \frac{1}{\frac{-2x-22}{x+5}} = \frac{x+5}{-2(x+11)}.\] On this face of it this is perfectly well-defined at $-5$.

However, if you decide that $g$ is not defined at $-5$, you might then conclude that $f\circ g$ (the function "apply $g$ and then $f$") can't be defined at $-5$, since after all you can't apply $g$ in that case.

A relatively sophisticated perspective on this is that "$f \circ g$ has a *removable singularity* at $-5$", that is to say, a point at which the function is technically not defined, but for which there is a perfectly good value (and indeed, only one value) the function *could* have that would be consistent with its behaviour elsewhere – in this case, you can extend $h$ by setting $h(-5) = 0$.

In fact, we tend to come across this kind of situation all the time, and usually we just plain ignore it – e.g. when cancelling $z$ from $xz/yz$, we rarely bother to say "except when $z = 0$". It's rarely problematic to just remove all removable singularities as soon as they turn up: having a function defined on a bigger set than you strictly need isn't a problem because you can always just restrict it to a smaller one.

However, in a question like this which is specifically asking about domains, it pays to be precise – and that means that whenever you replace a function with its definition, you must ensure that the argument belongs to its domain, possibly restricting your own domain as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In order to "evaluate" $f(g(x))$, We need all $x$ for which $g(x)$ exists AND for which $f(g(x))$ exists.

$g(x)$ exists unless $x=-5$.

$f(g(x))$ exists unless

\begin{align}
   g(x) &= 3 \\
   \dfrac{x-7}{x+5} &= 3 \\
   x &= -11
\end{align}

So the domain is $\mathbb R \setminus \{-5,-11\}$

Answer (score 0):

g(x)is undefined when x=-5.Now,h(x) is undefined when x=-11. Since g(x) is an input function, it cannot take value of -11.Solve g(x)=(x-7)/(x+5)=-11. Solution: x = 6.
So, final answer: domain of h(x) is all real numbers except x= 5 and x=-6.

Comment: Sorry, x=5,and x=6 POSITIVE SIX

Comment: You should use Mathjax (see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/491874). Please make sure you are answering all the OPs concerns (e.g. the formula for $h(x)$. You should be also able to edit your own answer rather than add comments about mistakes. Finally, why is it relevant to solve $g(x)=-11$?